# In android How to load the html file in webview ,property set to match parent?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to load **.html** file in webview. The property- height and width is set as match parent. Still the content (image and text) is not getting properly aligned within the webview.? How this can be achieved.

```
wb.setBackgroundColor(0);
wb.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your html/css. It is the only place that you have any chance of changing appearance.

Try this:

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20 Safari/537.31");
```

To make the webview run in desktop mode.

Comment: If the webview property is been set to match-parent. Doesn't the content should get the same.?

Comment: And it looks fine on in a normal browser? Can you post the html?

Comment: im not using a browser, rather inflating it on just a layout using webview

Comment: I know. But does it look right if you put in on PC and open in firefox or chrome. I suspect the error to lie in the HTML.